# How to format an excel table containing double headers in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with the following format:

NB. The following example is a shortened version of a table, featuring only one category as an example. The actual table has category names listed in the top row and months of the year (from Jan 2021 to Dec 2022) in the row below. Each subsequent row or column shows the values for each month. In the first table below, columns A, B, and C are additional information needed. However, everything from column D onwards is the table section with double headers and categorical information.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | ... | Column N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Category 1 | Col4 | ... | ColN |
| Parent/ Child Name | ID | Parent/ Child | Jan 2021 | Feb 2021 | ... | Dec 2022 |
| Jason | 1 | Parent | 1000 | 2000 | ... | 1500 |
| Timmy | 2 | Child | 600 | 1000 | ... | 600 |
| Sarah | 3 | Child | 400 | 1000 | ... | 900 |

I am trying to do some transformations to achieve the following result:

| Parent/ Child Name | ID | Category | Parent/ Child | Year | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jason | 1 | Category 1 | Parent | 2021 | Jan | 1000 |
| Timmy | 2 | Category 1 | Child | 2021 | Jan | 600 |
| Sarah | 3 | Category 1 | Child | 2021 | Jan | 400 |
| Jason | 1 | Category 1 | Parent | 2021 | Feb | 2000 |
| Timmy | 2 | Category 1 | Child | 2021 | Feb | 1000 |
| Sarah | 3 | Category 1 | Child | 2021 | Feb | 1000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Person N | ID N | Category N | Parent/ Child N | Year N | Month N | Value N |

I have tried by means of pivoting, transposing etc but I have not been able to achieve my desired result. I'm fairly new to using power query/ M code but I can't seem to find something relevant to help me achieve my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hereby i send you M codes which includes [category] column.

[image]

*//change data source with replacement in the first source sentence below*

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\zhenger\Desktop\powerquery sample.xlsx"), null, true),
    table_Sheet = Source{[Item="table",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(table_Sheet),

    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Transposed Table",{"Column1"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Custom", each "-"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Custom", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5"}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[Column1], [Custom], Text.From([Column2], "zh-CN")}, ""), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Column1", "Custom", "Column2"}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Merged", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5"}),
    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Reordered Columns1"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"-Parent/ Child Name", type text}, {"-ID", Int64.Type}, {"-Parent/ Child", type text}, {"Category 1-2021/1/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/2/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/3/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/4/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/5/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/6/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/7/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/8/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/9/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/10/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/11/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2021/12/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/1/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/2/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/3/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/4/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/5/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/6/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/7/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/8/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/9/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/10/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/11/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 1-2022/12/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/1/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/2/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/3/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/4/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/5/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/6/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/7/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/8/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/9/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/10/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/11/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2021/12/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/1/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/2/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/3/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/4/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/5/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/6/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/7/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/8/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/9/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/10/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/11/1", Int64.Type}, {"Category 2-2022/12/1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"-Parent/ Child Name", "-ID", "-Parent/ Child"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"-"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Attribute.1", type text}, {"Attribute.2", type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Attribute.1", "Category"}, {"Attribute.2", "date"}}),
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Year", each Date.Year([date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Year", "Month", each Date.Month([date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Inserted Month",{"-Parent/ Child Name", "-ID", "-Parent/ Child", "Category", "date", "Year", "Month", "Value"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.
The "trick" is to unpivot the "Date" Columns

***Note: Since you only show a single category, it was unclear how that would propagate, so I ignored it. You will need to modify the code to better account for changes. I suspect you will need to do a `Table.Group` for each category, and then output the category as a single column, in addition to the code below.***

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Remove top row and promote next row to headers
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

//Unpivot the "Date" columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted Headers", 
        {"Parent/ Child Name", "ID", "Parent/ Child"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Set data type of Date columns to datetime
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", type datetime}}),

//Sort ascending by Date and then by ID
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}, {"ID", Order.Ascending}}),

//Add Custom column for Year and Month
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Year", each Date.Year([Attribute]), Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Month", each DateTime.ToText([Attribute], "MMM"), type text),

//Remove unneeded columns and set desired order of remaining columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Reordered Columns"= Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",
        {"Parent/ Child Name", "ID", "Parent/ Child", "Year", "Month", "Value"}),

//Set all data types
    #"Set Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",
        List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(#"Reordered Columns"), {type text, Int64.Type, type text, Int64.Type, type text, Int64.Type}}))
        
in
    #"Set Types"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. When you say unpivot the date columns, do you mean select all the columns that has a date and then say unpivot other columns?

Some clarity on the categories. There are several categories and each category has values for each month of the year for 2021 and 2022.

Comment: @SashilParuk Your description of Category is not specific enough for me to act on. And your example only includes a single category. If you cannot figure out how to deal with it, I suggest you edit your question to provide a more realistic example. WRT your pivot question, it is the opposite of what you write.

Comment: My apologies. I edited the description of my question. I hope that helps. I was unable to use your solution because the requirements for the data changed. I do appreciate the assistance though.

Comment: @SashilParuk I assume you mean that, in your example, where you have cells containing `Col4` and `ColN` those should be categories.  If that is the case, we can just extract the list of categories and add that as a column. But since you've already accepted an answer, I won't bother at this time.